# How do I throw an error and exit inside Mata

Tags: stata

I'm writing a function in Stata where I do some logical checks and possibly throw an error. Could look something like this:

```
if ! r(N) {
    disp as error "There are no observations with a value of 1 in the subgroup."
    exit
}
```

Now, I'm also running some Mata code and I would like to do logical checks in Mata as well and possibly throw an error like the one above. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on the `exit()` and `error()` functions of Mata.

```
help mf_exit 

help mf_error
```

Comment: Thanks, the `_error(errnum, errtext)` seems to do the job.